# YouTube Upload Error - Upload failed: Can't process file

Tags: java, youtube, upload, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using this sample application for uploading a video on to YouTube. Initially I can able to upload the videos successfully without any issue, but after few days suddenly I have been facing the below error.

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java

After completing upload, when I check the video in the Videos list of my channel, there it is showing an error(Upload failed: Can't process file) like below

[image]

The class I am using is

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadVideo.java

And while executing, the messages in the console are as in the below.

```
Jul 15, 2017 2:02:59 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\Krishna\.oauth-credentials
Jul 15, 2017 2:02:59 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\Krishna\.oauth-credentials

is is not empty
Initiation Started
Initiation Completed
Upload in progress
Upload percentage: 10485760
Upload Completed!

================== Returned Video ==================

  - Id: wYB8OfEe9jU
  - Title: ex
  - Tags: [video, file]
  - Privacy Status: public
  - Video Count: 0
```

Comment: You may try clearing your internet cache/temp files. It may happen when the same video failed to upload twice. Also, it is possible that there's issues with the video file on the conversion side of things. Check this links: [1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/nhsDwlRUZXc) and [2](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/StaGwb5BuBE).

Comment: @abielita Very thanks for your comment. I have tried by clearing cache/temp files, but still I am getting the error. Also here I am not converting the video and previously the same video got uploaded successfully and after few days the issue is happening with the same video only.

Answer (score 3):

Your upload limit might have hit with your sample account on YouTube. I remember when I first started using YouTube, and used the Sample Account, and sooner or later I couldn't upload anymore videos. I had to create a full account with YouTube. I would try to login with a Google account you've, or even making a Google account and signing in with that Google account and see if that works for you!

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your comments. I tried your solution. But still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like these the best thing is to try different little changes:

- Change the file extension of your video a few times
- Clear your internet cache/files using for example CCleaner
- Change your browser
- Try using a real Google account to log in to YouTube, as your sample account may have reached an upload limit

I hope these propositions help you. I think the problem you are having is occuring during the conversion or the encoding. Maybe this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/D_zRLrzgofs) could help you.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your comments. I tried your solution. But still I am getting the same error.