# Bug with uploading using youtube API?

Tags: node.js, youtube-api

I'm uploading videos using youtube API v3.

All was Ok until I copied and renamed my video file via node js:

```
fs.createReadStream(old_path).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(new_path));
```

After it, after uploading, in my video manager page (https://www.youtube.com/my_video) I have error: "Upload failed: can't process file". But in my app i recieved video ID in response. I've uploaded that file several times with the same result. But luckily I have original (not renamed) file in my backup, and I uploaded it successfully.

By the way, when I tried to upload the renamed file manually (through the browser), it was successful.

p.s. When I use

```
fs.writeFileSync(new_path, fs.readFileSync(old_path));
```

for copying and rename files, uploading also was successful.
I tried to do it with a bunch of files, with same results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [reference post 1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/VX0xlTXYFCE) and [reference post 2](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/nhsDwlRUZXc) from YouTube help forum where the user has encountered the same issue.

The same issue was cited in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295782/youtube-upload-error-upload-failed-cant-process-file) as well.

Where the recommendation are the same as what I have given.

> It's possible there's issues with the video file on the conversion
>   side of things.

Another reason maybe is the [file format](https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402).

Currently the supported formats are listed below:

> - .MOV
> - .MPEG4
> - MP4
> - .AVI
> - .WMV
> - .MPEGPS
> - .FLV
> - 3GPP
> - WebM

Try to check [Recommended upload encoding settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171) for your videos on youtube as well.